# Homepage Not Found Error

Tags: errors, 404-error, homepage

Ok, so for some reason my homepage always comes up as "page not found". I have searched through countless other threads discussing this same issue, but none of the answers seemed to help me. I'm new to having a website, so I'm have no idea what to do.

When I started my website, the "page not found" error always came up, but I assumed it was because I had deleted the sample post and didn't have any other posts. When I started posting and things didn't change, I changed my settings to "static page", which worked... for a few hours. When I logged back in later that day, the error started coming up again.

I have tried changing my home page from "your latest posts" (the page comes up with a "page not found" error, even though I have two posts) to "static page" (when I created a page and made it my front page, "page not found" still came up when I tried to access my home page) and vice versa.

I have tried changing the theme but nothing changed. 
I tried updating my permalink settings. 
I tried clearing my cache and trying a different browser.

Please help!

Comment: Hi. Please try switching to default theme and disabling plugins. Also, set your permalink to `plain` in permalink settings. See how does this affect your website.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try my best to guide you trought some ideas that could solve your problem.

## 1 - Make sure your .htaccess is set to default

If you check the WordPress CODEX, you could compare your default .htaccess to the one you have on your root folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Source : https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

## 2 - Create a new homepage

You could try to create a new *Page* and go on `Settings > Reading` then at the option *Front Page Display* try to check the option « A static page (select below) » and get your new created page.

After you could try to update the *Permalinks* while setting them to `Default`.

## 3 - Try to install a freshly new WordPress

The last solution for me would be to create a completly new WordPress and check if the problem still happend without additionnal modifications.

---

If you could send us a link or some errors, it would help us to help you !